# run time modification of strings.xml

Tags: android

Is it possbile to write String into string.xml from the code? if yes please post the code for the same.
I want to use the same string.xml for the all the language strings at wanted to modify at run time

Comment: Why don't you provide different files (strings.xml) for different languages.

Comment: if my application is supporting more than 50 language is then i need to write one string 50 times for all the language so

Comment: If you want to give your app in 50 language, obviously you've to quote all strings in all those languages.

Comment: But i don't want to do that so only i want to write it in the string.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have dynamic string depends on locale or language why not try storing it into SQL Lite ?

Comment: Ya I have thought to do it storing in the database only...but again db size will increase. anyway thanks for the ans.

Answer (score 1):

String.xml are like string constants..

You can only use it when needed.

You will not be able to change the content.